# Существует ли Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) или его аналог в C++?

Tags: c++, windows

В среде .NET есть замечательный асинхронный паттерн [TAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx), есть ли нечто подобное на C++ (не CLI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует предложение [Resumable Functions (N4402)](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4402.pdf) - но его еще не включили в стандарт. Если будете искать в инете статьи - будьте внимательнее, большинство статей описывают предыдущие редакции.